# regex: a character should be present followed by another escape character

Tags: python, regex, backslash, findall

I am looking for a search pattern. There is a particular pattern which should not be followed inside another pattern. Somehow if this pattern is present, then `<` and `>` characters should be followed by escape `\` character. The characters can be present if they are not in the pattern.

I tried doing it this way:
    `input_string = '<First tag:<Second tag:hello>tag ends>'
    re.findall('(?<!\\)<.*?:.*?(?<!\\)>',input_string)`

Expected output:
    `['<Second tag:hello>']`

What I got is:
    `['<First tag:<Second tag:hello>']`

I tried with this pattern:
     `(?<!\\)<[^(?<!\\)<.*:]+:[^(?<!\\)<.*:]+?(?<!\\)>`

This passes the above example, but for this input:
    `input_str = '<First tag:\<Second tag:hello>tag ends> <First tag:<Second tag:hello\>tag ends> <First tag:\<Second tag:hello\>tag ends>'`

it fails.

This is the expected output:
    `['<First tag:\<Second tag:hello>','<Second tag:hello\>tag ends>','<First tag:\<Second tag:hello\>tag ends>']`

Comment: Don't use regex to parse anything with infinite nesting. It won't work.

Comment: So you want the innermost non-escaped `<` to `>`? That should be doable with regex.

Comment: @TemporalWolf Yes, exactly.. with a `:` in between `<` and `>`

Answer (score 0):

`(?<!\\)<(?:[^<>]|\\<|\\>)+:(?:[^<>]|\\<|\\>)*[^\\]>`

Gives:

```
$1 - <First tag:\<Second tag:hello>
$1 - <Second tag:hello\>tag ends>
$1 - <First tag:\<Second tag:hello\>tag ends>
```

for your second example:

Breakdown:

`(?<!\\)` Negative look behind -> it cannot start with a `\` in front of it.

`<` Begin with an opening angle bracket

`(?:` Start a non-capturing group: I want to group stuff but I don't want additional groups

```
[^<>] Any character that is not an angle bracket

| or

\\< An escaped left bracket

| or

\\> An escaped right bracket
```

`)+` Close the group... duplicate it 1 or more times.

`:` A semi colon

`(?:[^<>]|\\<|\\>)*` The same noncapturing group, 0 or more times.

`[^\\]>` Finally, it must end in anything except a `\` followed by a right angle bracket. `\\` is used because it must be escaped.

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mT1pE6/3) link if you want to test it.

This updated regex will accept: `<a:a>` as an example of the smallest valid match

Comment: :Still here it accepts some unwanted inputs, like`<hello>` and `/<hello>`.. I want this to be  in this format `<Some text:Some other text>`, but not nested

Comment: Fixed, as requested.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. but sorry to say this..may be i confused u.. `<Some tag:Another tag>` here these `Some tag` and `Another tag` can contain `<` and `>` inside, if these characters are not in the pattern. `<string:another<string>` this is accepted as 2nd `<` is not in pattern.

Comment: as QPaysTaxes mentioned, it seems now that you're wanting the ability to nest things, which regex is not well suited for.

What are you using it for, as your examples don't make any sense: This is increasingly looking like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)